# real random number

Tags: php, javascript, random

I have 5 jpg, named 01.jpg, 02.jpg..... 05.jpg. I have a little script that generate a number between 1-5 and shop up the jpg associated with it.... fine... But each time i reload the page, the picture is "supposed" to be random, and so different, but only 5 image, i get the same image on reload "a lot more" that i what to.... so the question is... Hot to make sure, on the reload of the web page the random number should be between 1-5 and NOT the same as it was the second before... so with that i will be sure to see on 5 consecutive reload the 5 picture at least !....

php of ajvascript please

here is the code :

```
<style type="text/css">
#photo { background-image: url(http://www.something/pano-0<?php echo mt_rand (1,5) ?>.jpg); } 
</style>
```

note:
for people that tell it's a sequence... no i like the random... at least do not choose the same

let say if #3 show, you random... and you can have 1,2,3,4,5, let get 2, if 3, re-random!

Comment: You probably won't be able to do it with Javascript. With PHP, you'll likely have to store the last image in `$_SESSION`

Comment: a cookie can be used... that's my idea to go for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very similar to @Jon Snyder's answer, but using `$_SESSION` instead of `$_GET`:

```
<?php
    // initialize session
    session_start();

    // array of possible images
    $images = array('01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg', '05.jpg');

    // check if user has seen an image before
    $last = isset($_SESSION['last_img']) ? $_SESSION['last_img'] : -1;

    // generate a random number that isn't the same as $last
    do { $num = rand(0, count($images)-1); } while ($num == $last);

    // display image
    echo '<img src="' . $images[$num] . '">' . PHP_EOL;

    // save last image in $_SESSION
    $_SESSION['last_img'] = $num;
?>
```

Comment: each time the page is reload, the session start will be called, is it ok ?

Comment: yes, that's fine. from the manual entry: `session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one`

Answer (score 4):

Roll a die.  Do you ever get the same number twice or even three times in a row?  Do you doubt the die's randomness?

With 5 images, you have a 20% chance that the image this time will be the same as the last one.  You don't want a random distribution.  You just want to rotate them every time.  We promise not to tell your users it's not truly random ;)

Comment: Beat me by a second, was about to say the same...5 pics, all different in each reload, it's not a "random" sequence, period. When numbers gets higher, that's another story.

Comment: Slower than me by 5 minutes but 3 more votes already. Guess you're just more eloquent :P

Answer (score 3):

When you make the request for the next image, append a query string parameter with the id of the current picture.  Then in your php code grab the value and use it to generate a random number that is not the same.

http://yourdomain/randomPicture.php?last=1

```
<?php
$last = $_GET['last'];

do {
    $next = rand(5);
} while( $next != $last);

echo '<img src="/picture'.$next.'.jpg" />';

echo '<a href="/randomPicture.php?last='.$next.'" >next</a>';
```

Comment: note that I DONT MAKE REQUEST, the user HIT the browser reload button... i dont do anything !

Answer (score 2):

If you really want it to be random, you will et the same number multiple times in a row - especially with such a small range of 1-5

You could specifically code to remember the last number and if the new number matches, generate again - but in reality, a random number is just that.

Ok, technically it's a pseudo-random number but for what you're dealing with it makes no difference

Comment: is it possible, when web browser reload is HIT, to check the css content of a div in the last page in the browser memory, it can do the trick ?

Comment: Marc no it's not un;ess the previous page has specifically recorded the information somewhere for you to retrieve be that Cookies in JS or Cookies/Sessions server-side. The web is stateless - each page you retrieve has no direct knowledge of any other page

Answer (score -1):

It might help if you can share the code that you are currently using to generate a random number. And even if you are generating truly random numbers, it is entirely possible to not see all 5 images in 5 reloads. In fact, it is highly unlikely.

Here is some pseudocode that might help:

```
int lastRandomNumber = -1;

function getRandom() : int {
 int temp = rand();
 while (temp == lastRandomNumber && lastRandomNumber != -1) { 
  temp = rand();
 }
 lastRandomNumber = temp;
 return lastRandomNumber;
}
```

This keeps a reference to the last randomly generated number and each time you ask for a new one it will keep regenerating until it gets a new value. However, depending on your generator there is the unlikely possibility that you get stuck in a very long loop.

edit: why was this voted down?